# Ansible jinja2 filter ipaddress

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have 3 servers A, B, C. When I run the below in j2 template, it pulls all 3 servers.

How can I ignore the server that runs the template?

For ex, if server A runs, it should fetch only server B & C.

```
"retry_join": ["
                {% for host in groups['servers']%}
                  {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host'] }}
                  {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              "]
```

Answer (score 2):

Exclude `inventory_hostname` from your servers list:

```
{% for host in groups['servers'] | difference([inventory_hostname]) %}
```

Comment: Oh, nice one! This is a very neat solution!

Comment: I am pulling the server list using dynamic inventory script. When using difference([inventory_hostname]), didn't see any change in the list.

"retry_join": ["A, B,C"]

Comment: Sounds strange to me... debug `groups['servers']` and `inventory_hostname` to see if current host is really in the servers group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a check like this one to verify that your loop variable is not the current host:

```
{% if host != inventory_hostname %}
  {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host'] }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: yep :) deleting comment.